# Why do the anticommutation relations imply Fermi–Dirac statistics (Pauli Exclusion Principle) for the field quanta?

Tags: fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle

I was reading the following article [Fermion FIelds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermionic_field) and discovered the following passage not fully explained to me :

> It is these anticommutation relations that imply Fermi–Dirac
>   statistics for the field quanta. They also result in the Pauli
>   exclusion principle: two fermionic particles cannot occupy the same
>   state at the same time.

What is the proof that the anticommutation relations of the Fermion Field gives rise to the Pauli Exclusion Principle?

Comment: It's called the [spin-statistic theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_statistics_theorem). The Pauli principle simply arises because, if the wavefunction(al) is anti-symmetric under swap and the two fermions are in the same state, then swapping changes nothing and the wavefunction(al) must have been zero already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keeping it simple, let's asume that $\psi(a)$ creates a particle in the state $a$ (i.e., characterized by some collection of quantum numbers that we call $a$),

$$ \psi(a)|0\rangle=|a\rangle .$$

and $\psi(b)$ does the same for $b$. We can create a state with two particles:

$$ \psi(b)\psi(a)|0\rangle = \psi(b)|a\rangle = |a;b\rangle $$

$$ \psi(a)\psi(b)|0\rangle = \psi(a)|b\rangle = |b;a\rangle $$

Since $\psi$ is anti-commutative,

$$ \psi(a)\psi(b) + \psi(b)\psi(a) = 0 .$$

So,

$$ |a;b\rangle = -|b;a\rangle, $$

that is, the state is antisymmetric under particle change, it has fermionic statistic.

In particular, if $b=a$,

$$ \psi(a)\psi(a) + \psi(a)\psi(a) = 2\psi(a)\psi(a) = 0$$

so,

$$ |a;a\rangle=0 .$$

This is  Pauli's Exclusion Principle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am stuck with understanding how to compute observables from a wavefunction of two fermions using the expressions provided above. For example how do you compute energy, momentum, and position? Thanks.

Comment: I think you should open another post for that question, because of you are not familiar with QFT the answer could be quite large.